# SQL Server : Inner /left join results in too many rows

Tags: mysql

Before anything else, I did check all the topics of "SQL Server : join results in too many rows" here in Stackoverflow and other websites but could not get the right code and therefore would be needing your expert advise as a rookie.
My task is to add 1 column from table B to table A that will provide the category of an item.
`Table A` has only 13288 rows but when I do join then the results will be 211657 rows. I tried `Left Join` was getting the same results of rows.
I wanted to do `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` but `table A` has duplicate `ticket_ids` as well so don't want to mess that too.

Here is the code that I have.

```
SELECT     Table1.*, Table2.Category
FROM       Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ticket_id =  Table2.ticket_id
```

Comment: Reason is Table2 has duplicated ticket_id. So Table1 joined with Table2 will expand rows. You could do "group by" ticket_id in Table2 before join.

Comment: I did try the below code but was getting, Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
`SELECT     Table1.*, 
( SELECT Table2.Category, MAX(Table2.ticket_id)
 FROM Table2
 GROUP BY Table2.ticket_id 
)
FROM       Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ticket_id =  Table2.ticket_id
COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS`

Comment: I do not know your data, so I do not know why you set **MAX** for ticket_id, and why you added **OLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS**. But try this query `SELECT Table1.*, Table2.Category
  FROM Table1 INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT MAX(Table2.Category) Category, Table2.ticket_id FROM Table2 GROUP BY Table2.ticket_id ) Table2
 ON Table1.ticket_id = Table2.ticket_id`

Comment: I used **MAX** to aggregate for **GROUP BY** to work, is it not the case whenever we do GROUP BY in sql?

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that the left join does not work. However, you can try using this:

```
SELECT     
   t1.*, (select t2.Category from Table2 as t2 where t2.ticket_id = t1.ticket_id limit 1) as Category
FROM       
   Table1 as t1
```

Comment: I think performance is not good. It (sql) should be kept Table2 in From, but make sub-query for "group by" first.

Comment: Where will I place COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS in your code? I tried to add it after Table1 as t1 or before the "as Category". but not working